# Efficient way to find nodes that have at least one child with specific attribute

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

i'm having a graph with multiple related nodes and i want to find all :A labeled nodes that are having at least one child labeled :B that have the same name and old_name.

The total number of nodes is +6M :A nodes and +60M :B nodes (every :B node is linked to only one :A node, but every :A node is connected to n :B nodes)

until now the most efficient way i found was to find the right :B nodes then to match them to the :A nodes, the other way around was way slower

Method 1

```
Match (b:B) 
where  b.val1<>b.val2 
with b
match (a:A)-[:Link]-(b)
return count(distinct a)
```

> Cypher version: CYPHER 3.5, planner: COST, runtime: COMPILED. 155619605 total db hits in 3756615 ms.

[planner result method 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5IDb.png)

Method 2

```
Match (a:A)-[:Link]-(b:B)
where b.val1<>b.val2 
return count(distinct a)
```

Result :

> Cypher version: CYPHER 3.5, planner: COST, runtime: COMPILED. 155619605 total db hits in 7122106 ms.

[planner result method 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MjZw.png)

Correct me if i'm wrong, but I think it should be faster to loop over the A nodes (as there are only +6M), rather than first finding a child :B that satisfies the condition and then looping over the related :A nodes.

Comment: i have tried to add a custom label to these specific child nodes :B on the ETL phase which results on less bd hits. Cypher version: CYPHER 3.5, planner: COST, runtime: COMPILED. 4307 total db hits

Comment: What about indexes?

Comment: yeah i'm doing it for other scenarios, but i think for these kind of columns it would be a bad idea to create index on, it will simply lead me to index almost every attribute.

Comment: Are your node counts correct? The "total db hits" you quote are too low if you really have 6 million `A` nodes and 60 million `B` nodes.

Comment: Yes, the 60 millions B and 6 million A are correct.
i think the main way for my queries to go faster is to reduce the db hits even more.

Comment: You may want to PROFILE both queries and add the query plan to your question, after expanding all elements of the plan.

Comment: Updated the question, thank you for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

Screening the :B labeled nodes and then looking for :A labeled nodes would be faster(Your first approach) because we have the chance that a large portion of the :B nodes would not satisfy the condition and then each :B is connected to only one :A.

**About the efficiency of your algorithm:**

As far as you say that each of the :B nodes is only connected to one :A node, I would recommend to use another property on each of the :B nodes to write the ID of the connected :A node. In this way, you will be left with at just one loop over the :B nodes and the loop over the :A nodes will be removed.

Then, your code will be as simple as follows:

```
Match (b:B) 
where  b.val1<>b.val2
return count(distinct b.aID)
```

Comment: Thank you.
Adding an attribute doesn't answer the question but it provided an easy solution.
It might have been useful on this case, but on a literal way, i'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: @pheno I am not relaxing your question, I am trying to help you to tackle the problem you are faced with, and a good approach would be to look backward and check the design problems. I just wanted to show you that the problem you are faced with, first of all, is a design issue. Notice that Stackoverflow is not for soving puzzles, it is a professional website.

Answer (score 0):

From the query plans you provided, the exact same plan is used in both cases. And in both cases, it's starting from all :A nodes, expanding :LINK relationships, and filtering. The only thing differing between the two is cache hits and misses.

You'll want to ensure you EXPLAIN any other potential queries to verify how it's going to be executed, as we want to see what execution will look like if we start from the :B nodes first. We'll need to force this, so we can first try using a [scan hint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/using/#query-using-scan-hint):

```
Match (b:B) 
using scan b:B
where  b.val1<>b.val2 
match (a:A)-[:Link]-(b)
return count(distinct a)
```

If an EXPLAIN of this starts with a label scan on :B nodes, then go ahead and PROFILE it and see how it performs.

Comment: Adding "using scan" didn't change anything on the explain/profile result.
But thank you for the hint, i never heard about it before.

Comment: That's odd, it should be changing the plan, as currently the plans you posted in your question begin with a label scan of `a:A` and never scan on :B. Can you post the query plans when using the scan hint?